# AdMob Interstitial Ads Issue

Tags: android, ads, interstitial

I am trying to add interstitial ads into my android application but I got the below error message:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 7895000 but found 7571000.  You must have the following declaration within the  element:

I tried adding the code to my AndroidManifest, but it didn't provide any solutions. Anyone have an idea?

Manifest Code:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="7895000 " />
<activity
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

Comment: please add the Manifest code.

Comment: Please check Manifest code in Question.. updated.

Comment: I think the version of the Admob ads jar is too old.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the meta-tag you are using is old. Answer is simple -

In Android Manifest, inside `<application>`, replace this -

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="7571000" />
```

With this -

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

In Gradle(If using Android Studio), put this -

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0'
```

**NOTE -** Put a `+` sign if this doesn't work like this -`ads:7.8.+` and `base:7.8.+` but is not very well as there are some issues with this.

If the problem still exists, try this. (Though I don't recommend it), use this -

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="7895000" />
```

If you like this answer, please mark it as `selected`.

**EDIT -** I made an app with apps just a few days ago, used this code and it works fine -

Manifest -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.sampleapp.app">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 
<!-- EXTRA CODE -->
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" /> 
</application>
</manifest>
```

Gradle -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sampleapp.app"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0' //LOOK HERE
}
```

**LATEST EDIT -** I think the Admob/Google Play Services library you are using is old. Try updating it.

Comment: Thanks for response but currently i am using your first solution but i got this error and also tried second as well but still error. Thanks

Comment: I already used 7895000 solutions but still error "Ads does not load".

Comment: I am using Eclipse not studio.

Comment: @harsh4u check the new answer, and using `Studio` is better though.

Comment: I added android:value="7895000" and its work but without it how can it work?

Comment: @harsh4u without `android:value="7895000"`, it can't work

Answer (score 0):

It's about incorrect Google Play services version.
Firsto of all add:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

to the application block.
Secondly make sure that in the gradle config you are using specific Google Play Services version like:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0'
```

Avoid using "+" like:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.+'
```

Because you may include library that is not supported at the moment.

Comment: Ok, so do you have meta-data in your AndroidManifest and <application> block? Which Google Play services are you using?

Comment: Yes, I have meta-data and application block. Google ads service using.